# How can I control pavucontrol in command line?

Tags: pulseaudio

I want to write a script where I can configure the settings in ***pavucontrol*** programmatically. It was suggested that I use ***pactl***.

I am quite lost on the options and I would like to know how the Tabs and options from in pavucontrol UI translate to pactl options?

[image: pavucontrol]

Comment: Update the question to show what you have tried and explain what did/didn't work

Comment: Im honestly stuck and dont know what to put after pactl. As a start, I want to change "Analog Stereo Output" to "Analog Stereo Input" in Configuration tab.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't "control pavucontrol from the command line".

You can control Pulseaudio with `pavucontrol`, or you can control Pulseaudio with `pactl` (or `pacmd`).

`pactl` has a limited set of commands, `pacmd` follows the general CLI syntax (see [man 5 pulse-cli-syntax](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-pulse-cli-syntax/) or do `pacmd --help`).

Changing "Analog Stereo Output" is IIRC done by changing the profiles, see `set-card-profile`. You'll still need other commands to identify your card etc.

If you want to change profiles by default, the Pulseaudio configuration files might be a better place to look.

Yes, it's quite complicated compared to `pavucontrol`, and will require a bit of reading and experimenting.

Answer (score 4):

i really can recommend using ***[PAmix](https://github.com/patroclos/PAmix)*** it is a nice tool:

[image: pamixer live in action]

But there are also some other tools out there like *[pamixer](https://github.com/cdemoulins/pamixer)*, *[ncpamixer](https://github.com/fulhax/ncpamixer)*.

if you can't or don't want to install any 3rd party, you can use [pactl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pactl) as suggested by [@dirkt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/193028/dirkt)